# Sobel edge-detection, weird output

Tags: edge-detection, sobel

I´m trying to implement a Sobel algorithm for edge-detection for a YUV camera stream. Initially it seems quite easy but I´m not sure if this approach is correct:

- I´m applying the filter just to the Y pixel component and doing U and V = 0 (black and white image).
- After, and in order to check the result, I´m sending frames through the serial port, but before I convert the image from YUV to jpg.

The black and white image works perfectly and I can see it on the PC application which I wrote, but when I´m applying the Sobel filter to Y component I´m getting this:
[image: Sobel output]

the code:

```
    #define index(xx, yy)  ((yy * width + xx) * 2) & 0xFFFFFFFE  // address multiple of 2

(...............)

for (y=1, y < height-1; y++){
    for (x=1, y < width-1; y++){
        pixel_valueY_h=0.0;
        pixel_valueY_v=0.0;
      for (j= -1; j<2; j++){
         for (i= -1; i<2; i++){

            offset= index(x+1, y+1);
            pixel_valueY_h += (sobel_h[j + 1][i + 1])* input[offset+1]; //offset+1=> Y component
            pixel_valueY_v += (sobel_v[j + 1][i + 1])* input[offset+1]; 

         }
      }
        offset = index(x,y);
        pixel_value= sqrt1((pixel_valueY_h * pixel_valueY_h)+(pixel_valueY_v * pixel_valueY_v));

        if (pixel_value > 255) pixel_value=255;
        if (pixel_value < 0) pixel_value=0;

        //output frame
        output[offset] &=0x00; //U and V components = 0
        output[offset+1] &=(255- (unsigned char)pixel_value );
    }
}

(...............)
```

Any clue about what is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please copy the source code directly into the post body. This makes it easier for other SO users to read, run and edit your code.

Comment: Can we see the image before Sobel ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got it working, the problem was the memory addressing using the macro: #define index(xx, yy)  ((yy * width + xx) * 2) & 0xFFFFFFFE which for some reason was giving incorrect addresses. 
Instead  I added the line ( ((yy * width + xx) * 2) & 0xFFFFFFFE) in the code and like that (without modifications) is working perfectly.

Thanks.